# Difference of row values by matching values in another column in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame generated from a call to Pandas.io.json.json_normalize(). Here is an 
example:

```
dfIn = pd.DataFrame({'seed':[1324367672,1324367672,1324367673,1324367673,1324367674,1324367674], 'lanePolicy':[True,False,True,False,True,False,],
                   'stepsPerTrip':[40,37,93,72,23,70], 'density':[51,51,208,208,149,149]})
```

```
  seed       lanePolicy stepsPerTrip density
0 1324367672 True       40           51
1 1324367672 False      37           51
2 1324367673 True       93           208
3 1324367673 False      72           208
4 1324367674 True       23           149
5 1324367674 False      70           149
```

Note that there are pairs of matching values in `dfIn['seed']` with one `True` and one `False` value in `dfIn['lanePolicy']`. It is also the case that if `dfIn['seed']` matches for two given rows, `dfIn['densitiy']` will match as well. I would like to compute a table similar to the following:

```
dfDesired = pd.DataFrame({'seed':[1324367672,1324367673,1324367674], 
                   'stepsTrue':[40,93,23], 'stepsFalse':[37,72,70], 'stepsDiff':[3, 21, -47], 'density':[51,208,149]})
```

```
  seed       stepsTrue stepsFalse stepsDiff density
0 1324367672 40        37         3         51
1 1324367673 93        72         21        208
2 1324367674 23        70         -47       149
```

In particular, I'm looking for the values in `dfDesired['stepsDiff']`, which are the differences between `dfIn['stepsPerTrip']` for the associated `False` and `True` values of `dfIn['lanePolicy']` for each pair of matching `dfIn['seed']`. Note also that `dfDesired` should have half the number of rows as `dfIn`.

I am able to calculate the values of that single column with:

```
dfDiff = dfIn.loc[dfIn['lanePolicy'] == True]['stepsPerTrip'].reset_index()['stepsPerTrip'] - dfIn.loc[dfIn['lanePolicy'] == False]['stepsPerTrip'].reset_index()['stepsPerTrip']
```

```
0     3
1    21
2   -47
Name: stepsPerTrip, dtype: int64
```

However, I would like to make a new DataFrame that preserves the other columns. I have also tried the following, but get an incorrect result:

```
dfDesired = dfIn.groupby('seed').apply(lambda x:x.loc[x['lanePolicy']==True]['stepsPerTrip']-x.loc[x['lanePolicy']==False]['stepsPerTrip'])
```

```
seed         
1324367672  0   NaN
            1   NaN
1324367673  2   NaN
            3   NaN
1324367674  4   NaN
            5   NaN
Name: stepsPerTrip, dtype: float64
```

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), subtract columns by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and for `density` column add Series with `seed` without duplicated with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = dfIn.pivot('seed','lanePolicy','stepsPerTrip').add_prefix('steps')
df['stepsDiff'] = df['stepsTrue'].sub(df['stepsFalse'])
df['density'] = dfIn.drop_duplicates('seed').set_index('seed')['density']
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
         seed  stepsFalse  stepsTrue  stepsDiff  density
0  1324367672          37         40          3       51
1  1324367673          72         93         21      208
2  1324367674          70         23        -47      149
```

Another solution is with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and default aggregate function `mean` if duplicates in columns `seed`, 'density' and `lanePolicy`:

```
df = (dfIn.pivot_table(index=['seed','density'], columns='lanePolicy',values='stepsPerTrip')
          .add_prefix('steps'))
df['stepsDiff'] = df['stepsTrue'].sub(df['stepsFalse'])
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
         seed  density  stepsFalse  stepsTrue  stepsDiff
0  1324367672       51          37         40          3
1  1324367673      208          72         93         21
2  1324367674      149          70         23        -47
```